# Unexpected query exception when using InMemoryDatabase

Tags: entity-framework-core, entity-framework-core-3.0

I have the following EF 3.0 query using `InMemoryDatabase`:

```
    IQueryable<Post> posts = _context.Posts.AsNoTracking();

    posts = posts.Where(x => x.Enabled);

    IQueryable<PostModel> models = null;

    try {

     models = jobs
      .Select(x => new PostModel {
        Id = x.Id,
        Enabled = x.Enabled,
        Category = x.Category == null ? null : new CategoryModel {
          Id = x.Category.Id,
          Name = x.Category.Name
        }
      );

      var result = await responses.ToListAsync();

    } catch (Exception e) {

       var ex = e;

    }
```

Initially `posts` have 2 items. After the filter `Where(x => x.Enabled)` I get one item.

But at the end `result` has no items ... It seems the existing item disappeared in the projection.

Then I tried the following (Removed the Category part):

```
     models = jobs
      .Select(x => new PostModel {
        Id = x.Id,
        Enabled = x.Enabled
      );

      var result = await responses.ToListAsync();
```

Now result has one item as expected ...

Any idea what might be wrong? I am really lost on this one.

Comment: Can you check your code? at the moment responses is not decleared, we only see you using it. apart from that what you descirbe seems really odd.

Comment: @Jan Yes, it is a really strange error but after sometime I found the problem. Is not easy to catch ... I added an answer myself as it might be useful to others ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This problem is hard to identify and I am posting the solution which might be useful for others in the future ...

In the `Post` model configuration `Category` property / relationship was set as **Required**.

When I added posts to `context` one of them had, by mistake, `Category` set to `null`.

If I was using SQL Server I would get an error when saving the context.

But because I am doing Testing and I was using InMemoryDatabase the invalid post was accepted.

And that led to the really strange error on the query ...

**Conclusion:**

In EF 3.0 (and previous versions) the Model is not validated at C# level.
So when using InMemoryDatabase wrong models will be saved and let to unexpected errors in queries.

There is also a Github issue in Entity Framework Core 3.0:
https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFrameworkCore/issues/10613